# HTML checkbox form php

Tags: php

Hello I have a problem with a Html form sending 0 instead of 1 to my database, it is set as tinyint 1
I have been messing with this for days.

I use phpmyadmin xampp server html php

```
<!--THIS IS SKILLS-->
 <?php



 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
if (!isset($_POST['action'])) 

 mysql_select_db("client", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO skills (driving_licence,HGV,engineer,carpenter,chef,PSV)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[driving_licence]','$_POST[HGV]','$_POST[engineer]','$_POST[carpenter]','$_POST[chef]','$_POST[PSV]')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
 echo "skills have been added";

 mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```

The form code is

```
<center><form method="post" action="skills.php">
<table cellspacing="50">
<tr>
<center><h1>Record Client Skills</h1></center>
<center><p> Please choose the relevent boxes</p></center>


<center><input type="checkbox" name="driving_licence" value="driving_licence">I have a Full UK Driving Licence<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="hdv" value="hgv">I hold a valid a HGV licence<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="engineer" value="engineer">I have an Engineering qualification <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="carpenter" value="carpenter">I have a Carpentry qualification <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="chef" value="chef">I have Catering qualification<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="psv licence" value="psv">I have a valid PSV licence<br>   
</tr>   
</table>

<input type="reset" value="Reset Form"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   <input type="submit" value="Send" />


 </center>
```

Can anyone help?

Rob

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the 0/1 stuff and worry about the gaping wide open [SQL injection vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com) in your code. But remember that checkboxes which are NOT selected in the form are **NOT** sent across the wire when the form is submitted.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I think your having a default value of 0 on your tinyint column and now trying to add strings to this column.

Comment: your fields are set to `tinyint (1)`? You're sending text values to it since `$_POST['hdv']` would equal `hgv` (based on your form)

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Set the checkboxes `value="1"`, otherwise the string `"driving_license"` is passed to your db-field which is `tinyint` :-(

AND: move to mysqli or PDO, mysql is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

and it's better to use `bit(1)` instead of `tinyint` for Boolean values, don't use root for connecting to mysql and use PDO or Mysqli, and finally it's not good way to print mysql errors for your users, use one of php database classes

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php



 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
 mysql_select_db("client", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO skills (driving_licence,HGV,engineer,carpenter,chef,PSV)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[driving_licence]','$_POST[HGV]','$_POST[engineer]','$_POST[carpenter]','$_POST[chef]','$_POST[PSV]')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
 echo "skills have been added";

 mysql_close($con);
}
 ?>
```

your Html form --

```
<center><form method="post" name="f1" action="skills.php">
<table cellspacing="50">
<tr>
<center><h1>Record Client Skills</h1></center>
<center><p> Please choose the relevent boxes</p></center>
<center><input type="checkbox" name="driving_licence" value="driving_licence">I have a Full UK Driving Licence<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="hdv" value="hgv">I hold a valid a HGV licence<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="engineer" value="engineer">I have an Engineering qualification <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="carpenter" value="carpenter">I have a Carpentry qualification <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="chef" value="chef">I have Catering qualification<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="psv licence" value="psv">I have a valid PSV licence<br>   
</tr>   
</table>
<input type="reset" value="Reset Form"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
</center>
```